# Rails 4 asset path/url helpers ignore host override option. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to override the CDN host configured for my app, just for a particular asset but it seems to ignore the option.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def icon(name, *opts)
    content_tag :svg, class: "icon", "aria-hidden" => true do
      # Use same origin asset host to avoid cross-origin issues with the <use> element.
      url = image_url("icons/entypo.svg##{name.to_s.dasherize}", host: "example.com")
      # Expected => https://example.com/assets/icons/entypo-14602e471cad33414596c56d831c5b8cdcec9477829b9eb6d34221faac7bb54d.svg
      # Actual => https://cdn.example.com/assets/icons/entypo-14602e471cad33414596c56d831c5b8cdcec9477829b9eb6d34221faac7bb54d.svg
      content_tag :use, nil, "xmlns:xlink" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href" => url
    end
  end
end

Example::Application.configure do
  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  config.asset_host = "example.com"
  config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN"] # => cdn.example.com
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = ENV["AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN"] # => cdn.example.com
end
```

Comment: Have you already restarted your server?

Comment: Did you try using `asset_url`? It wasn't clear to me if `image_url` uses it.

Comment: Yes, did both of those, twice for good measure.